# How to use momentjs on a Ember.js Router

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I'm trying to use:

`import moment from 'moment';`

but throw this error:

`Could not find module 'moment' imported from 'myproject/routes/myroute'`

If a simple use moment() as:

```
model(params){
  return this.get('store').query('myentity', {
    filter: {
      timestamp: {
        $ge: moment(params.day).startOf('day').format('x'),
        $le: moment(params.day).endOf('day').format('x')
      }
    }
  });
}
```

throw this error:

`Error while processing route: myroute Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined`

**Note 01**: I import momentjs from bower, update my jshintrc to include "moment" on predec and include "moment" on ember-cli-build too.

**Note 02**: I see ember-moment addon, but I want to learn how it work to apply to possible other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install something from bower, its just concatenated to your `vendor.js`. So it's not available as ES6 module, but if its exporting a global thats available. So you can just use the `moment` global.

Specifically for moment I recommend [ember-cli-moment-shim](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim).

In general for all modules I recommend to install them from `npm` and use [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify).

If you import something with `app.import` and want to use that as ES6 module, the right solution is to [write a `vendor-shim`](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset).

Answer (score 1):

I never tried momentjs with bower, but if you install something with bower, you are supposed to [import it in ember-cli-build.js](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset)

Other solution (which I prefer and use myself) is installing [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify). After that you can install moment (and any library which published in npm and able to work in browser environment) via npm (`npm install moment --save-dev`) and import it in your router/controller/whatever with `import moment from 'npm:moment'`.